# No x-auth-token header is found after logging in using Spring's MockMVC test API

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

Please consider the following configuration

Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedissonHttpSession
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.ja.pi" })
public class PiApp {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
```

Web security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserHandler userHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        //@formatter:off
            .anonymous().disable() // Disable anonymous sessions
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(getLoginSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(getLoginFailureHandler())
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/user/logout");
      //@formatter:on
    }
```

And the following test code:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = post("/login").contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").param("email", user.getEmail()).param("password", user.getPassword());

ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk());

MockHttpServletResponse response = result.andReturn().getResponse();
String token = response.getHeader("x-auth-token");
```

The problem is that `token` is always null and I can't perform actions that require an authenticated session!

But when I startup the Spring Boot application and use a REST client to simulate the same action of login, I find the `x-auth-token` header returned back in the HTTP response headers.

What should I do with the test API to allow receiving the `x-auth-token` ?

Comment: Can you show how you are getting an instance of MockMvc? What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I wasn't adding adding the `SessionRepositoryFilter` filter to the created web-app context. I posted a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I was creating the web-app context this way

```
mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();
```

But the solution is to obtain an instance of the SessionRepositoryFilter filter and add it to the web-app context. The filter is responsible for returning the `x-auth-token` header.

```
SessionRepositoryFilter<?> filter = webApplicationContext.getBean(SessionRepositoryFilter.class);
mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).addFilters(filter).apply(springSecurity()).build();
```

Comment: I am not what else I am missing. I tried several option still I am getting new x-auth-token(new session) for every request

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with that at the moment.